# Difference between widget form code variables

Tags: widgets

I'm attempting to create my first ever widget and was hoping someone could explain the difference between `$this` and `$instance` used in the following widget form code.

```
<?php
public function form($instance){ ?>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>">Title: 
        <input type="text" 
               name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" 
               value="<?php echo $instance['title']; ?>" 
               id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"
        />
    </label>  
<?php 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this` is the widget object, an instance of the relevant widget class. It includes things like the widget ID and class identifiers which are required for the method that generate the input id  and name attribute in the snippet

`$instance` is the array which includes the widget setting. The settings ae not stored as part of the object and therefor needs to be passed as a parameter

Comment: you are welcome, this is just another example of core developer not understanding OOP concepts :( in one of my plugins I just add the `$instance` to the object as an `instance` field, not only to make it more logical but also because sometimes if the front end needs to use a filter it is easier to just add a method for that without having to pass the `$instance` as some global.